# How to do synchonous HTTP requests using ktor-client-js version 2.x (without lots of boilerplate code)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor, kotlin-js, ktor-client

```kotlin
import io.ktor.client.request.*
...
val response: HttpResponse = client.get("https://example.com/version")
```

The code above uses `ktor-client-js` and the `get` and does **asynchronous** HTTP requests.

**The problem: How to make it synchronous *without* lots of boilerplate code?**

I am having a hard time finding an option. The only synchronized options seems not available for `kotlin-js`.

**Edit**: The compiler asks `client.get` inside a suspended method.

**Edit 2**: here is the code working.

[image]

If I try to remove the coroutine:
[image]

So I need to create coroutine and then boilerplate code to wait for the result. **How to make all of this simpler?**.

Comment: Suspend calls are executed one after another by default. Can you describe the problem you encounter in more detail?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman to make it short, the Ktor only does asynchronous calls. I could not find a synchronous option. I will try to edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Ktor does not do asynchronous calls on itself (that's why you can't find a synchronous option, the only option available already *is* synchronous). As a caller you can *make* it asynchronous, though. See my expanded answer for a detailed explanation.

Comment: I meant I am required to put the call inside a `launch{ }`

Comment: It is a suspend function, so it has to be called from another suspend function or from a coroutine (that you would create with `launch` or `async`). The choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in suspend functions is executed sequentially, as in any other function, there is no difference.

What *is* different, though, is that a suspend function is executed in the context of a coroutine scope that allows you to launch a *new* coroutine in that scope. You must do this explicitly though, by calling `launch` or `async` etc. So, everything is run synchronously, except you explicitly say otherwise.

In your example, you do not launch any new coroutines, so everything is run synchronously, each command waits for the completion of the previous command.
Everything aready works as you want it to be, there is no need to fix anything.

---

To address the question after the **edit**: Referencing what I said above, `client.get()` as a suspend function does only run asynchronous if *you* decide it should do so. That's an option, not a requirement. What it *does* require, though, is for you to call it in the context of a coroutine scope. That is among others, necessary for the internals of the function to switch the dispatcher to move the network request off the main thread. That doesn't need to concern you, though. The important thing is what the API exposes: `get()` is a suspend function, so you are required to call that function either from another suspend function or from an explicit coroutine scope.

To reiterate: Everything is already synchronous. Only when *you* decide to wrap it in a coroutine and launch it in the background by calling `async` it would become asynchronous. You do not do that, hence everything is already as you want it to be.

That can easily be verified by checking the return type of `client.get()`: If it *would* be asynchronous, the return value would need to be a Promise or some other deferred object (or whatever it is in kotlin-js). It isn't, though, it is a `HttpResponse`. Therefore it is *impossible* for that function to run asynchronously on itself. You can only make it asynchronous by wrapping it in an `async` block. *That* block would then instantly return a Promise which will be fulfilled asynchronously at a later time.

That is, in fact, one benefit of using coroutines: The decision if or when a piece of code should block can be made by the caller. In your example, the network IO of Ktor should definitely be asynchronous at *some* point (since it wouln't make any sense to freeze the entire app just to wait for a network response). But at what point specifically, that is up to you - the user of the Ktor-API - to decide.

Just get a coroutine scope (your framework should provide you with at least an application level coroutine scope) and go from there. At some point you need to launch a new coroutine so you can call suspend functions. It's entirely up to you to decide at what point, though. You could wrap your entire app in that coroutine if you really would want it to run 100% synchronous.

What would make more sense, though, would be to put everything related to the network request (including the call to `client.get()`) in that coroutine. Everything in that coroutine runs synchronous in relation to the other code in the coroutine. The coroutine itself will run asynchronously in relation to the rest of your app, as it should.

Comment: I edited the question to be more direct.

Comment: You mean `client.get()` can be synchronous without lots of code? I edited it again.

Comment: As I said many times by now, `client.get()` *is* synchronous. You can not *make* it so, it already is and always was. What is not synchronous is the coroutine that you *yourself* launch. But, well, that actually is the idea of a coroutine, it would be nonsense if it were otherwise. Your entire problem has nothing to do with the Ktor API, just with finding the proper place to start your coroutine. To reiterate the last two paragraphs of my answer, you can freely decide to put it wherever you want, there are no restrictions. Since you do not like where it is now, just put it somewhere else.

Comment: It´s only possible to call inside a coroutine because it´s suspended. And only `launch`  is available. My question is if there is a simple way of doing it without lots of code.

Comment: `launch` isn't much code, neither is adding `suspend` to your `postSyncMessage2` function (if that is what you want). How do you image it to get easier than that to enter a coroutine scope?

Comment: With `kotlin-js` is just a few lines. With `ktor-js` is much more lines, objects created and nested code blocks.